# Bash: Copy all files with same extension in root/current folder, except those whose filename contains certain string

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard, git-bash, cp

I have built script for copying multiple folders and files matching file types in one `cp` command line only like below:

```
today=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y");
cp -r ./{dir1,dir2,dir3,..,fi.le1.ext1,*.ext2,*.ext3} "../Target_$today/Subdir_$today/"
```

Now I want to copy all files of ".ext3" but leave out files that contain "lock" or "-lock" in their name. Because those files are auto-generated and so not required to backup those(eg. package-lock.json).

How can I do that without adding any `find` statement in between, but only using wildcard and negation operators ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `rsync -a --exclude '*lock*' ....` instead of `cp -r`?

Comment: No such command as `rsync` in GitBash, as I said in my comment below already and also mentioned in tags, the solution needs to work the same way in GitBash as well.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't know what tools exactly come with GitBash, but if you use it, it means that you are running on Windows. Did you consider installing Cygwin instead, which gives you the full selection of the "usual" tools?

Comment: I  have to make do with GitBash only as it's already installed, and the system I am saying about is office system, in which I don't have access to remove or install new apps, besides GitBash is much used nowadays and Cygwin is slowly becoming obsolete..

Comment: I get it. But just for information (in case you need it one day): You can install Cygwin locally also without admin rights (there is an option in the setup for this). As for obsoleteness of Cygwin, I think this depends on how well Microsoft improves their Ubuntu subsystem - but of course, I can't predict the future either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using extended glob:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob

cp -r ./{dir1,dir2,dir3,..,fi.le1.ext1,!(*lock).ext2,*.ext3} "../Target_$today/Subdir_$today/"
```

Comment: You answer is correct for original Unix and Linux shell, but I'm not sure if `git-bash` also supports globbing. I want this to work the same way in Windows Git Bash as well, like it works in Linux shells.

Comment: Sorry I don't have Windows to test there but this `extglob` is bash feature

Comment: @VickyDev, if it is bash it will work with any OS. Mind you `git-bash` has the latest and greatest bash version and GNU utilities. I installed `git-bash` and later `Cygwin` on my my windows machines to do the trivial things I would do with a Unix like environment, since I did not bother to use powershell.

Comment: @Jetchisel : When you run git-bash and Cygwin side by side, is there no conflict? And what are the advantages of `git` coming with git-bash, and `git` in the Cygwin distribution?

Comment: I don't use them the same time. now I mostly use Cygwin. git-bash has the prompt set-up already to show the branch of the repo